# How do I edit the placeholder text of an input box?

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

I'm setting up a nickname system for players in my .io game and I'm trying to put the placeholder text for my input box vertically in the center and completely visible unlike how it's not in the center vertically and it's being cut off. Also how do I make the font thinner? I' already tried using "text-weight: 1px" and it didn't work.

my CSS

```css
#nickname {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30%;
  height: 8%;
  outline: none;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form align="center">
    <label id='spawnif'>(press enter to spawn)</label>
    <input id='nickname' placeholder="Nickname">
  </form>
</div>
```

Screenshot of the page:

> [image: the box]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the line-height of the input box same as the height of the input box to make the text vertically centered, also try to set the height of input box in `px` instead of `%`

To make placeholder thin, set the `font-weight` on input box, as the placeholder will inherit same property. Also in your code set `font-weight` to correct value as 1px is not correct font-weight.

Also make sure the `font-size` of input box is always smaller then height of the box, else it will be cut from bottom.

```css
#nickname {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30%;
  height: 20px;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:20px;
  outline: none;
  font-weight:300; /* to make text thinner, make sure your font-family supports this font weight.*/
}

/* ::placeholder selector with vendor prefixes for diff browers */
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  opacity:1;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  opacity:1;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  opacity:1;
}
input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  opacity:1;
}
input::placeholder {
  color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form align="center">
    <label id='spawnif'>(press enter to spawn)</label>
    <input id='nickname' placeholder="Nickname">
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Hello Augustine Esenabhalu,

1. Font weight property will support values in multiples of 100 from 100 to 900 and these values defines from thin to thick of font weight(100 been lighter and 900 is Boldest). Other values that support this property are Normal, Bold, Bolder, Lighter. But this will not impact much and will not give you the desired font you want. I would suggest you to use a lighter font of the family you use for your site.
   For eg : If you are using Arial as the font family for your website then use Arial-light for placeholder.
2. For the placeholder to be aligned vertically center, you can add padding for the input field.
   Eg : In your case below values will solve the issue:
   **padding:3px 10px 0 10px;**

Hope this helps :)